# SQL Azure Issue

Tags: sql, azure, azure-sql-database

I have a strange thing happening in Azure SQL.

I have 4 Azure SQL Servers. In one Azure SQL Server (any database), this statement:

```
DECLARE @MyValues TABLE (MyKey uniqueidentifier not null) 
INSERT INTO @MyValues (MyKey)
SELECT Value FROM [dbo].[split]('CAC71EA6-A78C-4D79-B868-8F9C44B0996D;B768F7D7-108D-46E6-88F8-404D53E08560;FA61D499-9FBA-4F66-94A0-2A11A416C30A',',')
SELECT * FROM @MyValues MV
```

returns:

```
Msg 8152, Level 16, State 13, Line 2
String or binary data would be truncated.
The statement has been terminated.

(0 row(s) affected)
```

Which is as I would expect, since the split character ',' does not exist, and the entire string is not a GUID.

But in another, I get this

[image]

Running @@Version in both Azure SQL Servers shows the version is the same:

```
Microsoft SQL Azure (RTM) - 12.0.2000.8 
    Nov 29 2017 09:37:51 
    Copyright (C) 2017 Microsoft Corporation
```

So this is obviously a DB Server Setting. Does anyone know which setting affects this, and why?

SPLIT =

```
 CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[Split] (@List NVARCHAR(4000), @SplitOn NVARCHAR(5))
RETURNS @RtnValue TABLE (Id INT identity(1, 1), Value NVARCHAR(100))
AS
BEGIN
    WHILE (Ch arindex(@SplitOn, @List) > 0)
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO @RtnValue (value)
        SELECT Value = ltrim(rtrim(Substring(@List, 1, Charindex(@SplitOn, @List) - 1)))

        SET @List = Substring(@List, Charindex(@SplitOn, @List) + len(@SplitOn), len(@List))
    END

    INSERT INTO @RtnValue (Value)
    SELECT Value = ltrim(rtrim(@List))

    RETURN
END
GO
```

Many thanks.

Comment: Yes, the character `,` comma does not exist in the string. It's clearly delimited by `;` semicolons. Can't see your image but does your `[split]` even exist on server 2?

Comment: Jacob, I know the character does not exist, so I expect it to fail. But something on some servers allow it to return the first GUID.

Comment: Hence my 2nd question. Are they the same function? Let me rephrase: `[split]` is not a built in function. It is a custom function that someone created at your organization. Are your custom split functions the same across your servers?

Comment: Yes, sorry Jacob. Edited response to show Split, which is in both DB's and the same.

Comment: I agree with Jacob, i Guess the split function in this server has input of  , instead of ;

Comment: Now we're making progress!

Comment: :-) Thanks Jacob.

Comment: Azure SQL Database has its own string splitting function called `STRING_SPLIT` from compatibility level 130.  Don't roll your own!

Comment: Yes, Bob, agreed. There were written quite a few years back, so probably the best solution is to incorporate the built-in STRING_SPLIT function into our custom function. Thanks for the effort guys.